Possible to define an inner product on tempered distributions of compact support?
I am trying to understand why, in the context of reproducing kernel Hilbert spaces, there seems to always be a square-energy restriction on bandlimited functions in the Paley-Wiener space. (I get why this is useful for signal processing, to ensure sampling sums converge.)
The inverse Fourier transform maps the tempered distributions of compact support to a space of entire functions that do not grow too quickly in the sense that there is some choice of constants $A,N,B\geq 0$ such that $|f(z)| \leq A(1+|z|)^Ne^{B|\text{Im}z|}$.
If we replace the tempered distributions with finite-energy functions on some interval $I$, we get that the space is a reproducing kernel Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ if we use the norm induced by $L^2(I)$, i.e., $||\cdot ||_{\mathcal{H}} = ||\widehat{\cdot}||_{L^2(I)}.$ The Hilbert space property is easily shown from the fact that $L^2(I)$ is a Hilbert space.
But I don't think the tempered distributions of compact support form a Hilbert space, I don't even see how to define an inner product.
However, under the inverse Fourier transform, they map to a space of functions that have pointwise evaluations and I imagine the evaluation functional might be bounded with respect to a reasonably chosen norm. But the space would not be complete?
